# Issue with Office Web Apps - can't open Excel file, prompt for user name and password

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel, excel-services, office-web-apps

I can't open by Office Web Apps Excel file, SharePoint always prompt for user name and password and after entering correct user name and password it happens again and get error:

"An error has occurred trying to perform the requested action. Please try again."

Word and PowerPoint it works correct I'm able to open its by Office Web Apps without any problem.

I added Site to trust location in Internet Explorer but it also doesn't help.

Thanks for support and help,
Best regards
Andrzej